# Excel VBA - How to run a macro inside a module

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, macros

I have a delivery note spreadsheet that holds customer and product data. I want a button than when clicked Asks 'Do you want to Save as well as Print?'.
  I have recorded a macro for the file to be saved that works fine when the module is run on its own but when it is all put together in the code below I get the following error: 'Compile Error: Expected End Sub'. The else part also runs fine on its own. How do I solve this error and get the code to run? Thanks

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
MsgBox "Do you want to Save as well as Print?", vbYesNo
If answer = vbYes Then
Sub mac_SaveNote()
ChDir "C:\Users\User\Desktop\DeliveryNotes"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\User\Desktop\DeliveryNotes\" & Range("A11"), _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
Else
Sheets("Note 1").PrintOut , Copies:=2   'prints 2 copies of note1
Range("A11:J16").ClearContents          'clears customer data
Range("A18:I42").ClearContents          'clears product data
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

Move the sub out of the first and simply call it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
MsgBox "Do you want to Save as well as Print?", vbYesNo
If answer = vbYes Then

     mac_SaveNote

Else
    Sheets("Note 1").PrintOut , Copies:=2   'prints 2 copies of note1
    Range("A11:J16").ClearContents          'clears customer data
    Range("A18:I42").ClearContents          'clears product data
End If
End Sub

Sub mac_SaveNote()
ChDir "C:\Users\User\Desktop\DeliveryNotes"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\User\Desktop\DeliveryNotes\" & Range("A11"), _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Or just run the code as is and remove the Sub part

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
MsgBox "Do you want to Save as well as Print?", vbYesNo
If answer = vbYes Then

    ChDir "C:\Users\User\Desktop\DeliveryNotes"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\User\Desktop\DeliveryNotes\" & Range("A11"), _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

Else
    Sheets("Note 1").PrintOut , Copies:=2   'prints 2 copies of note1
    Range("A11:J16").ClearContents          'clears customer data
    Range("A18:I42").ClearContents          'clears product data
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The error has now gone but the document hasn't saved. I don't know whether this is to do with the filename being a cell that has its contents removed after code execution.